# Shape of trajectory of planetary motion if "leaking" mass at some rate.

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I know this question may be a bit more suitable for physics stackexchange, but I'm gonna make a try here to see if you like it.

It is well known that the trajectories of one body attracted by another in space are usually elliptic (periodic planetary motions) or hyperbolic (entry and leave like a lone comet entering solar system and gets slung out again).

---

Let us play with the thought that we instead have a body which leaks a small percentage of its mass each unit of time. For example if it is a gas planet which does not quite have enough gravity to keep all the mass in.

---

In such a scenario, what would the resulting equations of motion be and what would the solutions be? I suppose differential calculus and differential equations can be of a big help, but I have not derived anything specific.

---

**Own work**

Assuming the mass of the bigger body is so large so it stays fixed, the gravity force on the smaller body will be:

$${\bf F} = G\frac{m_1m_2({\bf v_1-v_0})}{|{\bf v_1-v_0}|^3}$$

Where $\bf v_0$ is a constant vector and $\bf v_1$ is a function of time.

Now using Newtons law of motion ${\bf F} = m{\bf a}$: $${\bf a_1}m_1 = G({\bf v_1-v_0})\frac{m_1m_0}{|{\bf v_1-v_0}|^3} \Leftrightarrow {\bf a_1} = G({\bf v_1-v_0})\frac{m_0}{|{\bf v_1-v_0}|^3}$$

It seems to me that $\bf a_1$ is independent of $m_1$, meaning that even if the object leaks mass, it's acceleration (and therefore motion) will remain unchanged. Am I missing something important here or is it a correct observation?

---

**Edit 2:** As mentioned by @GPhys, the formula ${\bf F} = m{\bf a}$ is not valid for when mass changes over time, so my conclusions above are probably not valid. However.. maybe we can use this other formula ${\bf F} = \frac{\partial {\bf p}}{\partial t}$ to get ahead?

Comment: See [Roche limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit)

Comment: comment on edit: F=ma is invalid if the mass is changing

Comment: @GPhys: Great! Then maybe I am mistaken. What is the general relationship between $\bf F$ and $\bf a$ now again? An integral?

Comment: @GPhys: Ah, maybe this one is more accurate then? ${\bf F }= \frac{\partial {\bf p}}{\partial t}$?

Comment: You can patch it up by adding an extra force $\mathbf{F}+\mathbf{u}dm/dt=m\mathbf{a}$ where $\mathbf{u}$ is the velocity of the ejected mass, but your question is unclear to me anyway. Why are you supposing the mass is leaking? Surely you cannot specify the equations of motion without this and surely gravitationally bound objects don't spontaneously separate! If you meant separation due to the gravitational pull of the intact body then the answer is exactly given by the Roche limit (and then the equations of motion are the usual gravitational ones for the separated small orbiting pieces)

Comment: I think it could work just using the formula I provided and replacing $m$ with some known $m(t)$ and see what the differentiation gives by using the product rule. I am no physicist and this is no physics forum, maybe mass could leak because the gravity is not strong enough to keep in light gases. Even earth for example can not keep hydrogen and helium ( I think ) in the atmosphere but it pours out in space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61918/discussion-between-gphys-and-mathreadler).